# How to store user data before deactivating user account ,and to restore user data after reactivating account in firebase in android

Tags: android, firebase

```
if(user!=null){
                pd.setMessage("Deactivating,please wait...");
                pd.show();
                user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(ProfileNavigation.this, "Account deactivated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                            Intent i=new Intent(ProfileNavigation.this, SignupActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }else{
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(ProfileNavigation.this, "Account cannot be deactivated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
```

By using above code I deleted user's account from firebase successfully under deactivating account and if user  wanted to  use my app  after deleting account, user has to register as new user. I wanted to store all data related to a particular user before deactivating account and if user wanted to reactivate his account at some point of time in future I wanted to allow user to start from the point where did he leave not as a new user.Can anyone help me please .Thanks in advance

Comment: Save the data before deleting in a temp node corresponding to PrimaryKey .

Comment: Above code completely deletes user account. How to deactivate a  firebaseuser(I am using sign in provider as email/password for my app) in android app and activate him when he prefers to Reactivate.Does firebase provide an option like deactivate account and reactivate the same account again.Can anyone help me please